# PHP - Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, object, this

I'm really sorry to be asking this question because I know it has been asked many times before (and I have read the threads) but I just can't puzzle this out.

I have a class:

```
class Fivehundredpx {
    private $_user;
    public $fivehundredpx;

    public function __construct(User $user){ 
        $this->_user = $user->data();
        $this->fivehundredpx = $user->data()->fivehundredpx;
    }

    public function fhpxEndpoint(){ //truncated - this function actually has a number of switch statements
        return $apistring = "https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?feature=user_favorites&username=". $this->fivehundredpx."&sort=rating&image_size=3&include_store=store_download&include_states=voted&consumer_key=I9CDYnaxrFxLTEvYxTmsDKZQlgStJG868GKb"; //this is the line that causes the error
    }

}
```

when fhpxEndpoint() is called I get the Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context message.

However if I add another method into the class:

```
public function userData(){
    print 'here is some text '. $this->fivehundredpx;
}
```

and call this from outside the class it prints out here is some text jinky32 as expected.

Any help much appreciated!

edit as per request:
method is called via

```
$fivehundredpx = new Fivehundredpx;
$obj = $fivehundredpx->fhpxApiConnect($fivehundredpx->fhpxEndpoint());
```

fhpxApiConnect() is:

```
public function fhpxApiConnect($apiString){
    print $apiString;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$apiString);
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
etc etc
```

printing out $apiString as I do in fhpxApiConnect() shows that the url has been constructed correctly and the name jinky32 has been inserted correctly but i still get the fatal error

EDIT:
OK, I've played around and found a way to get it to work.  If I change the class variable to

```
public static $fivehundredpx;
```

and then set it

```
public function __construct(User $user){
    self::$fivehundredpx=$user->data()->fivehundredpx;
}
```

I can then access it in fhpxEndpoint() using self::$fivehundredpx rather than $this->fivehundredpx

Comment: Please post the code where you actually call fhpxEndpoint().

Comment: Does method of class User returns $this?

Comment: @b4rt3kk do you mean within the constructor? if so no it doesn't

Comment: You should start by passing in an instance of User when instantiating `Fivehundredpx`. Right now it should fatal even before you call `fhpxEndpoint`

Comment: @tlenss yes you are right.  The Fivehundredpx object is actuallt instantiated elsewhere and does pass in the instance of User.  I just added it above in closer proximity to where I am using the instance but forgot to include the User param. Sorry

Comment: You get the fatal error after print $apiString? If so your problem is not the line mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function userData(){
    print 'here is some text '. Fivehundredpx::fivehundredpx();
}
```

or can try with:

```
public function userData(){
    $obj = new Fivehundredpx();
    print 'here is some text '. $obj->fivehundredpx();
}
```

Comment: doing this means that no longer prints out here is some text jinky32 and generates Fatal error: Call to undefined method Fivehundredpx::fivehundredpx()

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you can't access to a property of User like this:

```
$user->data()->fivehundredpx;
```

While method data of class User doesn't return your object. Add to method data:

```
return $this;
```

at the end.

Comment: I can access the value using $user->data()->fivehundredpx; though.  If I couldn't then surely my userData() method (which I am only using to try and debug this issue) wouldn't print out the value since $this->fivehundredpx is set in the constructor by $user->data()->fivehundredpx